# Why is Earth's atmosphere made almost entirely of $\rm N_2$ and $\rm O_2$ molecules rather than any of the nitrogen oxides?

Tags: atmospheric-science, biophysics, molecules, lightning, chemical-compounds

I assume the formation of $\rm N_2$ and $\rm O_2$  molecules is energetically favorable compared with N2O, NO, and NO2, etc., but are there some more intuitive arguments regarding the bonding and electronic structure of these various molecules that leads to the dominance of $\rm N_2$ and $\rm O_2$?  
I'm also wondering what role plants, or life in general, might play in this. Photosynthesis seems to produce O2 molecules as a biproduct rather than monatomic oxygen or NO2, for example. Similarly the biological nitrogen cycle seems to end up with N2 being emitted back into the atmosphere rather than N2O. 
Are there any examples of planetary atmospheres where nitrogen-oxygen compounds form a major component?

Comment: O2 is pretty reactive. There's mainly lots of O2 because of life, because O2 likes to react with stuff so unless you're always making it, it reacts itself away.

N2 is pretty unreactive and not light enough to just float away (like helium). So once it gets into the atmosphere it tends to stay there. I think there is so much of it because it can't really be incorporated into rocks. My guess is that the answer to your question is that alternative forms of photosynthesis which result in NO2 result in alternative "sugars" with less available energy than those that produce O2.

Answer (score 1):

The various nitrogen oxides are extremely reactive chemical compounds which means they have a strong tendency to react with other (trace) elements in the atmosphere. This means that they get scavenged out of the atmosphere almost as quickly as they are formed.